# Why [overflow: auto] does not work in Chrome?

Tags: asp.net, html, cross-browser

Why does the div go out of his parent in Chrome and they is not appeared both in FireFox!
In spite of everything is working great in IE8.

Chrome:

[image]

The code:

```
<div id="parentDIV" style="overflow: auto; height: 600px;">
    <!-- Child Control -->
    <GW1:OrgChart ID="OrgChart1" runat="server" /> 
</div>
```

**Edit**: When I specify the width for the parent div it works, but I don't prefer that. I tried to set the width to `100%` and it does not work.
Any idea!

Comment: did you check out developer tools in chrome? what do they tell you about the nested div?

Comment: I made a quick test (http://jsfiddle.net/TvUqr/2/) and it's working fine for me (even without fixed width)

Comment: @Teneff : Seems the problem is not in the `overflow`. Actually it's in the width of the parent div. when it does not have a specific width it does not stay inside its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent `div` needs to have a width for `overflow:auto` to work, otherwise it will expand to accommodate the width of all the children.

Using `width:100%` is the same as not specifying the width - the parent will simply expand since it doesn't have a limit.

Comment: You've specified the problem but can't I escape from specifying the width?

Comment: @Jack: No, the width needs to be defined somewhere. You might be able to use % width, just as long as it's not 100% (I haven't tried that though).